# 1968-ish Philips radio components question

Tags: components, identification, radio

I found a Philips radio/record player from I believe 1968 at a garage sale. I picked it up for $5. Sweet deal for me! I researched the cabinet to find it's general manufactured time frame. I've already repaired the record player but the radio is somewhat dysfunctional. Dysfunctional in that only the left side of the unit has sound while the right does not. I checked the speakers, and the balance selection knob works. I then started looking over the PCB board for burnt out components to which I found two ceramic cylinder type components that look like resistors. I thought maybe they were capacitors, but I'm really not sure. They have "M1" stamped on them (i'll attach a photo) and a diagram that looks like an AC voltage source diagram. Circle with a squiggly line throw the middle.
[image]

I'm not too familiar with components, just getting started with this radio cabinet. I'd like to replace these but I don't know what they are exactly?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If any further pictures are required I'd be more then happy to upload. Thanks

Edit:
Thanks Sparky256, no I haven't tried an ohmmeter as of yet.
user2943160: I'll attach some photos for location.

[[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Have you tried using an ohmmeter, or a capacitance meter? Looks like the part information burned or wore off. "M" is a designator for MOV, but given the age of this part "M" probably has nothing to do with its function. Unless someone knows it by heart, only a diagram or LCR meter could solve this issue.

Comment: Where in the circuit was this component removed from? The context will likely help identify the part.

Comment: Your photo shows a silkscreened printed wiring board; what was the designation on that board next to the mystery component?   R is for resistors, C for capacitors, D for diodes, Q for transistors, etc.

Comment: Whit3rd, the prints are R344, R346. So, these are resistors. I've looked on the other two components that are identical to the burnt ones, which are to the left in the photo and the only markings are the "M1" and the circle with the wavy line through them. There are no other markings to indicate what type of resistor these are.

Comment: The circle with the squiggly line in it looks like the Philips logo (but missing the stars).

Comment: M1.... could it be 1W instead?

Comment: The model number of the radio would be helpful. Back in the days it was common to have schematics, and there are people out there who preserve such old service documents.

Comment: Given their proximity to the power transistors, I would bet that they are emitter ballast resistors for the audio output stage. As such, they would be low-value, high current resistors -- something on the order of 1 ohm and several watts.

Comment: I can not upload any more photo's because I'm a newby here lol. But, Nils: there are no serial numbers or make and model stamps anywhere on the cabinet however, on the radio frame itself is a number what to me, looks like the serial number. But when I try searching for anything it comes up nul. This is what's printed on the frame. "Waller made in Japan" on a sticky paper the numbers "02234". In the middle of the frame are printed "53205409" under that is printed "7 2 5 0". And thats it on the entire unit. Nothing printed on the PCB board or anywhere else.

Comment: Dave: tracing the soldering lines on the bottom it looks like the resistor closest to the transistor are connected. I am having troubles locating my OHM meter to verify this connection however.  But you are right in that they are for the audio output. There's identical resisters on the left side of the board, and the left side audio works fine.

Comment: @carloc you could be right there about it being a W. I'm inclined to think not though, only because i'm reading it right to left. And it was printed on what I presume to be the anode side. But again, i could be very wrong on those assumptions.

Comment: ok after cleaning up the board more and inside the cabinet I came to find a piece of one of these resistors that had broken apart when it burnt up. Fortunately, it still had the printing of the resistor values, which are from left to right: M1  1ΩK, 29.  Further searching hasn't really given me much information about them. Google shows me lists of PDF files that have common lettering, but theres nothing in them that is helping me figure out a suitable replacement. I'll keep looking and post my findings if any.